# pop a viewController without release

Tags: ios, iphone

People, i want to pop a viewController using the normal back button on NavigationView controller without release the customized view that was created by the user, any one know some way to do that?
Because the natural flow of the navigation controller is release the "poped" viewController! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why don't you keep a strong reference of the view controller that is pushed, So that when its popped you still have the view controller and its view state in memory.

Comment: Maintain a strong reference to the view and it should stay in memory.

Comment: @madmik, it's a bad idea to keep a strong reference to the view but not the view CONTROLLER. The view controller's view my have IBAction links that would point to the view controller and cause a crash if you triggered the action. San is right to suggest keeping a strong reference to the view CONTROLLER.

Comment: yeah. sorry. I meant view controller. thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to retain a copy of the view controller elsewhere. Perhaps inside the class containing the navigation controller. Then push this back onto the stack when required.

Additionally check out [UINavigationControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

can you save the datas in the "popped" view controller？ when it comes out again, populate it? When view controller is popped, it should be released.

Answer (score 0):

You can navigation.viewControllers array copy in to global array before pop the custom view. After pop view global navigation.viewControllers assign global array.

NSArray create in AppDelegate

```
appDelegate.nav = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

then after assign global array in poped view

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  self.navigationController.viewControllers = appDelegate.nav;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well people tha answer is, make your controller from the StoryBoard, and don't use segue to call.

```
if(comparacao == nil)
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle: nil];
    comparacao = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ComparacaoView"];
}
[self.navigationController pushViewController:comparacao animated:YES];
```

So with this, I every use the before instance created, and every thing that my user do in this view was maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Swift Code:

```
@IBAction func pushButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
     if let exitingSecViewCon = secondViewController {
           navigationController?.pushViewController(exitingSecViewCon, animated: true)
     }else{
           self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "second", sender: self)
       }
 }

var secondViewController: SecondViewController?   //Keep Strong Pointer


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "second" {
        if let sec = segue.destination as? SecondViewController {
             sec.name = "ABC"
             secondViewController = sec;

         }
     }
}
```

Console Log:(Same address for SecondViewController)

```
ADD=<RetainCount.SecondViewController: 0x7fb5ac630cf0>  
ADD=<RetainCount.SecondViewController: 0x7fb5ac630cf0>  
ADD=<RetainCount.SecondViewController: 0x7fb5ac630cf0>
```